# confused on what this initialization method is accepting these type of parameters?

Tags: swift, class, initialization

//sorry this maybe a little vague but I'm having trouble figuring out why super.init has 2 parameters of type length???  Maybe this is too vague but I'm very confused??

```
init(length: Int) {

super.init(length: length, width: length) 


}
```

Comment: They are not of type length. They get the value of `length` parameter to this `init` method.

Comment: @SamiKuhmonen but shouldn't there be a variable name and followed by the colons and then the type?

Comment: No, this is calling, not defining a method

Answer (score 1):

You are calling `super` to init a square (so to speak), where `length = width = the value you pass into the subclass's init`.

It's better to change the `super.init` labels to `height:width:` to avoid these kinds of confusion.

**Edit:**

```
super.init(length: length, width: length)
            |        |      |       |
            |        |      |      Another parameter's value
            |        |     Another parameter's name
            |   This is the parameter's value, not type
        This is a parameter's name
```

The 'type' only applies when you **declare** a function:

```
class SuperClass {
    init(length: Int, width: Int) {
        // do something
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm confused on why the 2 parameters length and width have "type" length?? Shouldn't they have type Int or be of a valid type?

Comment: ohh I see, i did not know of that, where the types are applied only when a function is declared.......Thank you so much, I'm actually studying a swift book and the problem is that many little concepts like this are not sized down to understandable pieces.

Comment: one last question, I tried chaining the parameter names to height and width to avoid confusing myself with the length parameter accepted in the init() but it wants me to use the same parameter names used in the superclass's init() method......?

Comment: You have to change the parameter's name in the superclass' `init` too (assuming that you have access to the superclass code)

Comment: Oh I see, so I can't use my own parameter name.

Comment: last question, sorry, the book states "if you are creating an initializer in a subclass with the same name as the superclass’s designated initializer, you must override it, even if the subclass is using it as a convenience initializer." .....dont all initializers have the same name 'init'? what do they mean by it having the same "name"?

Comment: A class can have multiple `init`: `init(aInt : Int); init(aFloat : Float); init(aString : String)`. Each of them is considered to have a different name, but really, a different **method signature**.

Comment: so basically 2 methods with the same method signature technically "have the same name" ?......if this is true, how would I deal with different inits with the same signatures?